# Symfony2 - php app/console getting a parse error on a HostGator shared host

Tags: php, symfony, deployment, console

I've followed the steps to deploying the site remotely, but when I attempt to run php app/console inside the symfony folder I'm getting the following:

**Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_STRING, expecting T_CONSTANT_ENCAPSED_STRING or '(' in /home4/username/symfony_project/app/console on line 13**

Is there is an option I missed when deploying?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nvm, figured it out need to use '/opt/php55/php' instead of 'php'.

e.g., /opt/php55/bin/php app/console